# How to write a program that lives for a configurable period of time?

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have written a script that runs for a certain amount of duration and this duration can be updated and the program should terminate after running for the updated duration.
For eg:
If I start a program that runs for 60 seconds and later before these 60 seconds have passed, I update the duration of the program to run for another 30 seconds, it should stay alive for another 30 seconds. The update can happen multiple times based on the user's request. How do I do it?
I tried solving the problem in the following way, but it doesn't work i.e. the main thread doesn't exit:

**Server side code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket
import threading
import time

from threading import Thread

class StoppableThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event.is_set()

def killer(sleep_time):

    for i in range(sleep_time):
        print ("sleepin - %s" % i)
        time.sleep(1)


t = StoppableThread(target=killer, args=(60,))
t.name = "killer_thread"
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()


HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65433

def foo(conn, addr):
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            print (data)
            if not data:
                break
            for th in threading.enumerate():
                if th.name == "killer_thread":
                    th.stop()

            data = int(data)
            if not data<20:
                raise Exception

            t = StoppableThread(target=killer, args=(data,))
            t.name = "killer_thread"
            t.setDaemon(True)
            t.start()

            conn.sendall(bytes(data))

def active_count_checker():
    while True:
        for i in enumerate():
            print (i.name())
        if threading.active_count() == 1:
            exit(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen()

        while True:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            threading.Thread(target=foo, args=(conn, addr)).start()
```

**Client side code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65433

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b'5')
    data = s.recv(1024)

print('Received', repr(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable `extension` and update it when you get the new `time_interval`.

```
def killer(sleep_time):

    while sleep_time:
        print ("sleeping - %s" % i)
        time.sleep(1)
        sleep_time += extension-1
        extension = 0
```